# Creating vice versa multipoint feature within ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relates

The [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m700000066000000) says about a multipoint feature:

> Sometimes, you need to create a feature that has more than one physical part but only references one set of attributes in the database. These are called multipoint features for point or multipart features for line and polygon features.

I have an reversed situation. I need to create a single feature with multilined attribute table.

For example I have a building under construction. Every day it is raised at specific height. The contour of this building is always the same, but the height is changing every time.

So I need few attribute lines to describe such building.

Comment: No, the model is 1 row in the database is 1 feature, it's just that a multipoint has multiple parts but is still stored in one geometry object. You can do a one-to-many relate to link one geometry to many records or write your own custom implementation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Within*** an attribute table a geometry (be it single or multi-part) only ever has a one-to-one correspondence with its attributes.

Consequently, to meet your one-to-many requirement I think you will need to use a [Relate (or a Relationship Class)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002v000000) to a second table:

> Relates defined in ArcMap are essentially the same as simple
>   relationship classes defined in a geodatabase, except that they are
>   saved with the map instead of in a geodatabase.
>
> If a feature class in a geodatabase participates in a relationship
>   class, that relationship class will be immediately available for use.
>   You don't need to relate the tables in ArcMap.
>
> Relates (or relationship classes) are the best way to associate data
>   that has a 1:M relationship.

Comment: As I understood it is impossible to make such vector file as I needed, so your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the related table already mentioned by @Polygeo, the other option is to store your polygons in a Z aware feature class. then you can add a Z value (height or level) to your vertices so that each level has its own attribute table, but shares exactly the same XY coordinates as the base of your building (or not, if upper levels are smaller than your base)

Comment: I don't follow what you are suggesting here but it sounds interesting.  Can you describe it in more detail, perhaps with a picture or two?  Are you perhaps saying to have a series of stacked polygon features above each building footprint.  Would this solution require a 3D Analyst license?